# Animation - How to choose what happened when animation is done

Tags: html, css, animation

Animation - How to choose what happened when animation done.
When I hover my input it cut the animation and return to start
I want when it done it will go slow down start point and doesn't immediate.

for example: I am hover the text and it go up and when I am stop hover it reverse in same time (go down).

```css
.form {
  padding: 12px 25% 10px 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-1";
  grid-gap: 7px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.form input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgb(240, 219, 219),
    1px 1px 1px 1px rgb(155, 35, 35);
  border: 1px solid rgb(236, 160, 160);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form > .box {
  grid-area: grid-1;
}

.form > .box > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form > .box > input:focus + label {
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: all 2.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
    <label>first name</label>
  </div>

</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, your transition is only active when the label is focused, because  `transition` is only specified on the label state. You want to add another CSS transition **when the label is not focused:**

```
.form > .box > input + label {
  transition: all 2.3s ease;
}
```

```css
.form {
  padding: 12px 25% 10px 25%;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-areas: "grid-1";
  grid-gap: 7px;
}

.box {
  position: relative;
  height: 50px;
}

.form input {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  outline: 0;
  padding-top: 20px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 1px rgb(240, 219, 219),
    1px 1px 1px 1px rgb(155, 35, 35);
  border: 1px solid rgb(236, 160, 160);
  border-radius: 10px;
  font-size: 16px;
  z-index: 1;
}

.form > .box {
  grid-area: grid-1;
}

.form > .box > label {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 5px;
  padding-left: 7px;
  pointer-events: none;
}

.form > .box > input + label {
  transition: all 2.3s ease;
}

.form > .box > input:focus + label {
  color: aqua;
  font-size: 14px;
  transform: translateY(-20px);
  transition: all 2.3s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="form">

  <div class="box">
    <input type="text">
    <label>first name</label>
  </div>

</div>
```